# Fibonacci Counter in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in React. I am trying to do a counter for a fibonacci sequence. For those who don't know what is a fibonacci sequence, here is a [guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). It works at the beginning and then it starts to go off sequence. I want to be able display the number in the fibonacci sequence and move up and down the sequence. Here is what my code so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      previous1: 1,
      previous2: 1,
      count: 1
    }

    this.clickDecrease = this.clickDecrease.bind(this);
    this.clickIncrease = this.clickIncrease.bind(this);
  }

  clickIncrease(e) {
    this.setState({
      previous1: this.state.count,
      previous2: this.state.previous1,
      count: this.state.previous1 + this.state.previous2
    });
  }

  clickDecrease(e) {
    this.setState({
      previous1: this.state.previous2,
      previous2: this.state.count - this.state.previous1,
      count: this.state.previous1
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        The current number is: {this.state.count}
        <button onClick={this.clickDecrease} className="btn btn-danger">-</button>
        <button onClick={this.clickIncrease} className="btn btn-primary">+</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to store the last two numbers in a property of the state so I can add them up to get the next sequence. However, it does not seems to work. What should I do to make this better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the working code, you don't need a separate count variable to store the series value, previous1 will always have that value.

**How to update series values:**

*During '+'* :  At each step `previous1` will be equals to `(previous1 + previous2)` and `previous2` will take the `previous1` value.

*During '-':* `previous1` will become `prevoious2` and `previous2` will take the value of `previous1 - previous2`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
       previous1: 1,
       previous2: 0,
    }

    this.clickDecrease = this.clickDecrease.bind(this);
    this.clickIncrease = this.clickIncrease.bind(this);
  }

  clickIncrease(e) {
     let a = this.state.previous1 + this.state.previous2;
     this.setState({
        previous1: a,
        previous2: this.state.previous1,
     });
  }

  clickDecrease(e) {
     this.setState({
        previous1: this.state.previous2,
        previous2: this.state.previous1 - this.state.previous2,
     });
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div>
          The current number is: {this.state.previous1}
          <br/>
          <button onClick={this.clickDecrease} className="btn btn-danger">-</button>
          <button onClick={this.clickIncrease} className="btn btn-primary">+</button>
       </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id ='app'/>
```

**Note:** Put the condition in decrease function, when the value of state variable will be 1 and 0, otherwise it will take the negative values.

Answer (score 0):

If you use React hooks, things can be quite simple. Use a ref to hold the previous count, when the current count changed, add the previous count and the current count together. that's all.

Here I moved hold the previous count into the `usePrevious` hook.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const previousCount = usePrevious(count); // hold the previous count

  const addCount = () => {
    setCount(count + previousCount);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>previousCount: {previousCount}</div>
      <div>count: {count}</div>
      <button onClick={addCount}>click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`usePrevious.js`:

```js
const usePrevious = value => {
  const ref = useRef(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);

  return ref.current;
};

export default usePrevious;
```